# topological space

Tags: general-topology, compactness, filters

Let $( X,\tau )$ be a $T_1$ topological space. Let $D = \{ d_n : n \in \omega \}$ be a countably infinite closed discrete subspace of $X$. Fix $P \in X$ and let $F \in \beta\omega- \omega$ be an ultrafilter and define a new topology $\sigma$ on $X$:

$\sigma = \{ U \in \tau∶ p \notin U \} \cup \{ U \in\tau : p \in U , \{ n \in \omega : d_n \in U \} \in F \}$

Do we have $( X, \sigma )$ a $T_1$ space, and strict containment $\sigma \subset \tau$?
We have for every $B \subset X$, $cl_\sigma (B ) \subset cl_\tau (B) \cup \{ p\}$. Can we say that for every non- closed $A$, $p \in cl_\sigma (A)$?

Note that $ \beta\omega $ means the Stone-Čech compatification.

Comment: Please choose a more descriptive, informative title.

Comment: Is $\beta\omega$ an ordinal product? If so, how do you subtract $\omega$? And how can an element of that be an ultrafilter?

Comment: @dfeuer Note the last line, it's the Stone-Čech compatification of $\omega\quad (= \mathbb{N})$.

Comment: So all that statement means is that $F$ is an ultrafilter on $\omega$?

Comment: @dfeuer A free ultrafilter, i.e. one that isn't of the form $F = \{ A : k \in A\}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: This has been asked on [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/137904/21564).

Answer (score 2):

First, one needs to check that $\sigma$ is a topology. That's an easy verification that I omit. $\sigma \subset \tau$ is clear by definition.

I assume that the $d_n$ are distinct, or at least each point appears only finitely often in the sequence $(d_n)$, otherwise $\sigma$ need not necessarily be $T_1$ (if $d_{n_k} = q \neq p$ for a sequence $(n_k)$, and $F$ is obtained from a free ultrafilter on $\{n_k : k \in \mathbb{N}\}$, then $p \in \overline{\{q\}}$).

Next, to check that $\sigma$ is a $T_1$ topology, we need to show that for every $x \neq y$ there is a $V \in \sigma$ with $y \in V$ but $x \notin V$. For $y \neq p$, choose $V = X \setminus \{x,\,p\}$. $V\in \tau$, since $\tau$ is $T_1$, $p \notin V$, hence $V \in\sigma$. For $y = p$, choose $V = X \setminus \{x\}$. $V \in \tau$, and $\{ n : d_n \in V\} \in F$, since $F$ is a free ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$ and hence contains every complement of a finite set.

We need not have strict containment, $\sigma = \tau$ is possible, since applying the same construction to $\sigma$, with the same $F$ yields $\sigma$ again.

> Can we say that for every non- closed $A$, $p \in \operatorname{cl}_\sigma (A)$?

No, in general that does not hold. Let, for example $(X,\,\tau)$ be $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology, and $D = \mathbb{N}$, $p = \frac12$.

The interval $I = (-2,\,-1)$ is not closed (neither in $\tau$ nor in $\sigma$), and its $\sigma$-closure does not contain $p$, since

$$U = (\frac14,\,\frac34) \cup \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left(n - \frac{1}{2^{n+2}},\, n + \frac{1}{2^{n+2}}\right)$$

is a $\sigma$-neighbourhood of $p$ that does not intersect $I$.